# Cordova Android app not working from Android 6 version onwards

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

I have build android app using cordova phonegap. But am facing issue when I installed app from Android 6 versions onwards it will show error as "App is unfortunately stopped" and it's not opened also. But for below 6 version it's installed and worked fine for me.

Then I removed the code of reading IMEI number from MainActivity.java file inside platforms/android/src/com/MainActivity.java" then app is worked fine in above android 6 version also. So I have doubt that this issue arise only when reading phone imei number from android 6 versions and above.

I used below given android permission for reading phone state in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

did u added any external plugins like getting wifi connection,imei number?i guess in that 6th version is not supprting with that

Comment: should go as a comment.

Comment: I have added both plugins but still app is not even working from above android 6 versions. Its showing message as "App is unfortunately stopped".